# How to create button with text under icon by reactjs?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

Now, I have component like this: [image]

code of it:

```
import React from "react";
import {withStyles} from "material-ui/styles";
import Settings from "material-ui-icons/Settings"; 
import Button from "material-ui/Button";

const styles = {
button: {
    color: "primary",
    height: 95,
    width: 95,
    disableRipple: "true",
    focusRipple: "true",
},
icon: {
    height: 35,
    width: 35,
    display: "block",
    float: "none",
},
text: {
    height: 35,
    width: 35,
    display: "block",
    float: "none",
    marginTop: 10,
},
};

/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
const IconedLabel = ({classes}) => (
<section>
    <Button className={classes.iconButton} variant="raised" color="primary">
        <Settings className={classes.icon}/>
        <div className={classes.text}>Message</div>
    </Button>
</section>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(IconedLabel);
```

But need to button, that in top part contains icon and text message in bottom.
I use reactjs and material-ui lib from here https://material-ui-next.com/demos/buttons/

Comment: This is easily achievable with css. Having your icon and div with a `display: block;float: none;` property should do the trick.

Comment: @3Dos Do I need to use other propetries to move text under icon? just this style-attributes didn't help me(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Button` component uses flexbox to control the layout/alignment of content. To align the content vertically (so the icon is above the text), you can simply change the `flex-direction` to `column`.

This style needs to be applied to an element inside the button component, not to the root element. You can use the `classes` property to override all of the styles in a component.

In this case, you want to add `flexDirection: column` to the `label` class.

[Documentation on class overrides in material ui v1](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/)

Here's a working example. Hope it helps.

```js
const [React, ReactDOM, Button, Settings, withStyles] = [window.React, window.ReactDOM, window['material-ui'].Button, ({className}) => <i className={`material-icons ${className}`}>settings</i>, window['material-ui'].withStyles]
// Ignore code above this line

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    height: 95, // setting height/width is optional
  },
  label: {
    // Aligns the content of the button vertically.
    flexDirection: 'column'
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: '32px !important',
    marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit
  }
})

const CustomButton = ({ classes }) => (
  <Button
    /* Use classes property to inject custom styles */
    classes={{ root: classes.button, label: classes.label }}
    variant="raised"
    color="primary"
    disableRipple={true}
  >
    <Settings className={classes.icon} />
    Message
  </Button>
)

const WrappedCustomButton = withStyles(styles)(CustomButton)
ReactDOM.render(<WrappedCustomButton />, document.querySelector('#root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/material-ui@1.0.0-beta.40/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"><div id="root" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A (potentially bad) solution would simply be:

```
.MuiIconButton-label {
  flex-direction: column
}
```

I say bad, because you might want to use it in it's standard format elsewhere.

What I opted to do was add a class name `nav-bar-icon-wrapper` to the IconButton & set the flex direction in it's parent:

```
.nav-bar-icon-wrapper {
  flex-direction: column
}

.MuiIconButton-label {
  flex-direction: inherit
}
```

If I run into instance later where I want the icon/label button to be standard, I'll just add a new class `default-icon-wrapper` and css that handles that:

```
.default-icon-wrapper {
  flex-direction: row
}
```

---

**FWIW:**
I preach the BEM http://getbem.com/introduction/ convention **AND** that whenever you make a component, you add an optional `modifier` prop.

I have functions in a shared dir that looks these:

```
export function BEMifyThis(modifier) {
    return (klass) => BEMify(klass, modifier)
}

export function BEMify(klass, modifier=false) {
    if (modifier) {
      klass += ` ${klass}-${modifier}`
    }
    return klass
}
```

Then I use that everywhere in my component so the user can access the component elements as a group or individually using their modifiers.

```
import {BEMifyThis} from '../shared/bem'
const BEMify = BEMifyThis(this.props.modifier)

className={"navbar__menu_item")}
becomes
className={BEMify("navbar__menu_item")}
```

so something like `navbar__menu_item` becomes `navbar__menu_item navbar__menu_item-logout`